# Return error in Single

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java2

I have a method:

```
override fun signIn(userName: String, password: String): Single<User> {
        return userRemoteDataStore.signIn(userName, password)
                .map { mapper.mapFromEntity(it) }


    }
```

User has two fields: `username` and `error`.
I want to check if field `error`is not null I want to return this error. In this case I always get onSuccess. How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48205590/error-handling-in-rxjava

Comment: no, in this case I want to return error after get response from backend, in case from other question I want to validate before api call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your behavior can be achived via `flatMap`

```
override fun signIn(userName: String, password: String): Single<User> {
    return userRemoteDataStore.signIn(userName, password)
            .map { mapper.mapFromEntity(it) }
            .flatMap { user ->
                user.error
                    ?.let { error -> Single.error(MyException(error)) }
                    ?: Single.just(user)
            }
}
```